# JSF page freezes when is reloaded many times

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, threadpool

I use this code to fetch data from database table.

```
public List<Dashboard> getDashboardList() throws SQLException {

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }

        //get database connection
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();

        if (con == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS");

        //get customer data from database
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        List<Dashboard> list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();

        while (result.next()) {
            Dashboard cust = new Dashboard();

            cust.setUser(result.getString("SessionTTL"));
            cust.setPassword(result.getString("MAXACTIVEUSERS"));


            //store all data into a List
            list.add(cust);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This code is a part of a JSF page which is deployed on glassfish server. The problem is that when I reload the JSF page many times(around 8 times) the web page freezes. I suspect that the thread pool is fill and there is no space for new connections. How I can solve the problem? Close the connection when the query is finished or there is another way?

Best wishes

Comment: Could you please show us how you configure that data source? Is it pooled in the first place?

Comment: Is this code really part of your jsf page (so you are using JSP)? Or is it part of a backing bean? If the latter, what is the scope of the bean?

Comment: I made several screen shots of the pool configuration: http://imageshack.us/g/827/screenshotbg.png/

Comment: Yes, it's managed managed bean - here is the code http://pastebin.com/ErM3e1Rm

Comment: That's interesting - I get this error message when I open the page many times - Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Yes you should close your connection when your done by explicitly calling the `close()` method. Closing a connection will release database resources.

UPDATE: And you should close the `PreparedStatement` as well (with `close()`). I would also recommend to handle SQLExceptions in your method and not throw it, since you need to make sure that your statement and connection are closed even if an exception occurs.

Something like this:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement();
    try {
        // Work with the statement
    catch (SQLException e ) {
        // Handle exceptions
} catch (SQLException e {
    // Handle exceptions
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

Furthermore, you should not query the database in a bean field's getter method. Getters can be called several times during each request. The more elegant way would be to prepare the DashboardList in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` of your bean.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I have to place @PostConstruct before public List<Dashboard> getDashboardList() throws SQLException { ?

Comment: No, the `getDashboardList()` is a getter for a bean field. Create a new method, e.g. `@PostConstruc public void init()` where you fill your DashboardList. The getter then only returns the filled list.

Comment: Now I get this error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded. I closed the connection with this statement - con.close();